Running R in VSCode - R not attached
I want to run R in VSCode. I have installed:

R 4.3.1
VSCode Extension for Running R

When I open up a new R file, a new R terminal opens, and the code I selected and pressed run on doesn't execute. VSCode says R interpreter not attached, and I'm unable to figure out how to do so. I also tried selecting the R terminal in the dropdown where powershell is
I am able to run Rscripts from the powershell when I'm in the folder that my R.exe file is in. For example, the following works for me:
.\Rscript.exe "C:\Users\Path\to\file\first_R.r"
Things I tried

Reinstalled the extension
Used the R terminal
Clicked to attach R terminal
I referenced this stackoverflow, another question (both are answered by u/coip,  the problem here is exactly what I face, but the solution doesn't work for me. Neither of the 2 options, ie. setting "r.rterm.windows" or setting up the integrated profile worked for me.

This is my current settings.json:
{
    "r.plot.defaults.colorTheme": "vscode",
    "r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.1\\bin\\R.exe",
    "r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.1\\bin\\R.exe",
    "r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
    "r.rterm.option": [
        "--no-save",
        "--no-restore",
        "--r-binary=C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.1\\bin\\R.exe"
    ],
    "files.associations": {
        "*.r": "r"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
               "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
               "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
             ],
             "args": [],
             "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "R": {
            "path": [
                "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.1\\bin\\R.exe"
            ]
        },
     },  
}```

Appreciate that I don't have admin access to set PATH variable. 


You can, in fact, set the path (just not permanently) without Admin access - I recommend a .bat file for convenience:
@echo off

:: set path to R
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\path\to\R

code --extensions-dir "C:\.vscode" 

Fair warning, I stopped using VSCode for R and mainly use it for Python (where this approach works) + Java Script so I didn't test again for R.
